# Mountain weather archive

Tags: mountaineering, weather

Are there any weather, or at least temperature, archives for mountains?

I have read that this information is very spotty, that it is not recorded for many mountains. In searching for this data, however, I have found weather services which *forecast* weather for mountains at various elevations.

Though obviously recorded temperature is better, it would be useful if there was at least an archive of the predicted temperature. That would be better than nothing, assuming these mountain weather forecasts are somewhat reliable, which is something I do not know.

**Are there any temperature archives for mountains?**

Comment: Mt. Washington for sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find decades of data for thousands of weather stations (in the Western US, Alaska and Hawaii) here:

[Western U.S. Climate Historical Summaries](https://wrcc.dri.edu/Climsum.html)

You can select the stations from a map or search by name. There are quite a few in mountainous areas

Answer (score 1):

At least in the US you can do this to various degrees depending on the mountain. For example, there is a weather station in Telluride CO at 9950 ft that you can search back at least 2 years

https://www.wunderground.com/personal-weather-station/dashboard?ID=KCOTELLU11#history/s20160625/e20160625/mdaily

For Mt Washington NH there is a weather station at 6266 ft that you can search back around 45 years

https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KMWN/1973/6/25/DailyHistory.html?req_city=&req_state=&req_statename=&reqdb.zip=&reqdb.magic=&reqdb.wmo=

The key is to know which mountains have weather stations and how long they have been there.

Answer (score 1):

France has a number of automatic snow and weather monitoring stations, notably in the Alps and Pyrenees, whose recordings are available online (as pictures, not data series AFAIK).

It seems [Meteo France](https://meteofrance.com/meteo-montagne) which runs them does not give the link to them on its public website anymore, but at least [this website](http://www.webcams-montagne.fr/nivoses.php) reproduces them daily and [keeps an archive of them](http://www.webcams-montagne.fr/archives-nivose.php)

Below an example: wind, air temperature, snow height for this week and past winter season:

[image] [image]